# Authentication with session when using Hangfire dashboard

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I'd like to use the Session property (Session["isAdmin"]) to determine whether or not a user should be able to view the Hangfire Dashboard.

The problem is that when i'm using

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

this is null - eventhough i'm using this property on my other pages where is has data in it.

I'm struggling in following code snippet. 
I want to let the admin role view the page.

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
        {
            var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;

            if (session == null || 
                session["username"] == null ||
                FindUserRole(session["username"].ToString()) != 
                 "ADMIN")
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Are there any other way I can do this easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the context you should be using the parameter provided. Something like this should be what you are after:

```
    public class HangfireAuthorization : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext currentContext)
        {
           return Boolean.Parse(currentContext.GetHttpContext().Session.GetString("isAdmin"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried this but the "currentContext" does not have a definition called "GetHttpContext()".

Comment: Are you using .net core? The latest version of Hangfire? Did you install the Hangfire.AspNetCore package?

Comment: @nipple1450 If this answer helped you please mark as the solution!

Comment: @Sebastian It looks like GetHttpContext() is only available for .NET Core. Is there a way to get the HttpContext using traditional ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works for .NET Core, however if you are using .NET Framework, then `GetHttpContext()` doesn't exist. I did find an answer that works from this GitHub Issue:

https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/978

If you register an `IHttpModule` and set the session state to required

`context.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);`

Then, `HttpContext.Current.Session` will not be null in the `HangfireAuthorizationFilter`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this. Do not forget session has limited time to expire.

```
public class HangfireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public object session;

    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        var sessionToCheck = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session?[YourSessionKeyHere];

        if (sessionToCheck != null)
        {
            session= sessionToCheck;

            return true;
        }
        else if (session != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```